# I need to select the rows which has 2 characters and 3 characters only if the next row also has 3 characters

Tags: sql, excel, vba, row, row-number

I need to select the rows which has 2 characters and 3 characters only if the next row also has 3 characters or blanks. I also need to ignore the rows with blanks. Please provide the solution in SQL/VBA.

For ex.

The column resembles like below

```
501  
502  
01  
02  
03  
504  
01  
02  
505
       
506  
507  
01  
02  
03
```

I am trying the below code:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE LEN(fieldname) = 2
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: I am trying the below code: 
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE LEN(feildname)=2
AND LEN(feildname)=3 IF  ALSO LEN(feildname+1)=3: 
This is something I am starting with but I dont know how to address the next row while using condition. Please do help if anybody has solution.

Comment: Great. Can you also show us the expected result.

Comment: Expected result is that rows with these values will only be selected 
501
01
02
03
01
02
505
506
01
02
03

Comment: Hey, edit the question instead!

Comment: Please do let me know if you have the solution! Thank you for the suggestions.